# Does silverstripe have recursive data relationships?

Tags: silverstripe

Does silverstripe have recursive data relationships? I tried to implement it and it gives no errors but the page is blank on modeladmin.

Example has_one recursive relation on Product to itself:

```
class Product extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar',
        'ProductCode' => 'Varchar',
        'Price' => 'Currency'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Product' => 'Product'
    );
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example for what you are asking it will make it much easier to get good responses

Comment: I added example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

There can be problems when doing this with Many_Many relationships, though.

Comment: please give some examples $Has_One and Many_Many relationships, it appears to be undocumented.

Comment: Your example looks absolutely fine, what trouble are you having?

Comment: trouble is dev/build does not reach/finish Product class and so ModelAdmin is blank. What could be wrong? I will be using $Many_Many more often, what can be the problems when used recursively?

Comment: I've just tested this with a self referencing has_one and the dev/build worked fine. I think there's either more going on than you're telling us. What version of SS are you using? RE: many_many - see https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/5659 for some information

Comment: I'm using version 3.4...What will change once version 4 is out? I know 4 is still Alpha though.

Comment: v3.4 should be fine. The reason the dev/build is not completing must be somewhat unrelated to the self-reference to Product. SS4's release will likely not have a big bearing on this issue

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan. All the best to Silverstripe!

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be "no" for this done in this way.  Where I've need this in the past I've created the "has one" as an "int" in the db array...

```
class Product extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar',
        'MyProductID' => 'Int',
    );

}
```

this means I've had to add [casting](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/model/data_types_and_casting/) for the summary field, custom [scaffolding](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/source-class-DataObject.html#1853-1914) for the search fields and in the `getCMSFields` to [`replaceField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/source-class-FieldList.html#202-224) the int field for a [DropdownField](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/class-DropdownField.html) to select a product.

Comment: but does Silverstripe have recursive data relationships? ALso product id in real world is not limited to int.

Comment: I gave my answer of "no"... so no.  And the code you have in your question with has_one Product would create an Int field called "ProductID" and _ALL_ ID's in silverstripe are under the control of the ORM and are Ints... so whilst you are right if you make your own system you can choose something else... but not in silverstripe and not for the example you've given.

Comment: Barry it would be good if you can give the $has_one definition for completeness, I'm taking a look at your solution, thanks

Comment: I'll leave this question to @DanHensby instead... he works for SilverStripe and his view / knowledge trumps mine.  Be Well :)